# Return a time zone string from a function

Tags: format-time-string

Is this how I can return a time zone string from a function?

```
(defun timezone (ptz)
    "Gets the Posix Timezone String for major locations."

    (cond
     ((equal ptz "Alaska")
         "ASKT9AKDT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00")
     ((equal ptz "Denver-Colorado")
         "MST7MDT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00")
     ((equal ptz "Argentina")
         "ART3")
     ((equal ptz "Greenland")
         "WGST3WGT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00")))
```

Comment: Well, what happens when you evaluate it, and then call it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely the wrong thing to do. At no point should you ever use strings like `"MST7MDT,M3.2.0/2:00:00,M11.1.0/2:00:00"` to specify a timezone. Instead, take a standardized name like “America/Denver” and look it up in the [time zone database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database). Emacs will even do that for you; just use the name whenever it wants a ZONE as an argument:

```lisp
(format-time-string "%FT%T%z" nil "America/Denver")
⇒ "2022-12-05T22:57:51-0700"

(format-time-string "%FT%T%z" nil "Europe/London")
⇒ "2022-12-06T05:57:51+0000"
```

Comment: So with Emacs I do not need to look up in the `time zone database`?  Just use `format-time-string` ?  But how can I determine the `zone` for `format-time-string`?

Comment: From the time zone database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#Names_of_time_zones

Comment: What is the nanosecond `%N` ?  Is it based on `60` or is it digital ?

Comment: `%N` shows nanoseconds as a 9-digit decimal fraction of a second: `(format-time-string "%FT%T.%N%z" nil "Europe/London") ==> "2022-12-06T16:21:19.539641390+0000"`